# C++ Calling a EXE from a method

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Hi i need to call a external EXE (same running exe )from a C++ method i used

```
system("filepath");
```

but in the current file closed and new exe doesn't create the new instance

How can i call a exe with absolute path ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776886%28VS.85%29.aspx), it should do the work.

Answer (score 3):

Look at [this example](http://goffconcepts.com/techarticles/development/cpp/createprocess.html) that uses WinAPI CreateProcess